# Serialize data in Kendo Multiselect within Kendo Grid to bind to array when updating?

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc, serialization, kendo-ui

I'm using a Kendo Multiselect within the editor template of a Kendo Grid in an effort to edit an int[] property of my data model.

Here is the model:

```
public class Project
{
    ...
    public int[] Staff { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

The partial containing the grid - it includes a serialization script for any array data. This gets triggered correctly, but trying the contents of the array at this point read as Object, not as integers.

```
<script>
function serialize(data) {
    for (var property in data) {
        if ($.isArray(data[property])) {
            serializeArray(property, data[property], data);
        }
    }
}
function serializeArray(prefix, array, result) {
    alert("prefix = " + prefix);
    alert("array = " + array);
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (var property in array[i]) {
            result[prefix + "[" + i + "]." + property] = array[i][property];
        }
    }
    alert("result = " + result);
}
</script>

<div>
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ProvostDevelopment.Models.Project>()
        .Name("ProjectGrid")
        .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.ID).Hidden();
            columns.Bound(c => c.ProjectName);
            columns.Bound(c => c.StartDate).ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(StartDate, \"MM/dd/yyyy\") #");
            columns.Bound(c => c.DueDate).ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(DueDate, \"MM/dd/yyyy\") #");
            columns.Bound(c => c.Current);
            columns.Bound(c => c.Complete);
            columns.Command(command => command.Edit().Text("Details")).Width(180);
        })
        .Scrollable()
        .Sortable()
        .Selectable()
        .Pageable(pageable => pageable
            .Refresh(true)
            .PageSizes(true)
            .ButtonCount(5))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.ID))
            .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Project"))
            .Create(create => create.Action("Create", "Project"))
            .Update(update => update.Action("Update", "Project").Type(HttpVerbs.Post).Data("serialize"))
        )
        .Editable(editable => editable
            .Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp)
            .TemplateName("ProjectEditor")
        )
        .HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "height:500px; "})
    )
</div>
```

In the project editor, I have tried a bunch of things, including using a MultiSelectFor or simply a MultiSelect and a HiddenFor. The data seems to get read in properly, but something changes on the way to the controller.

```
<script>
function onChange(e) {
    var arrayOfNames = this.value();
    $("#staffHidden").val(arrayOfNames);
}
</script>

...

<div class="col-md-11 details-item">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Staff, new { @class = "col-md-4 details-label" })
    @(Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(m => m.Staff)
        //.Name("Staff")
        .DataValueField("ID")
        .DataTextField("FullName")
        .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["Staff"])
        .Events(events => events
            .Change("onChange")
        )
        .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "col-md-7 details-editor" })
    )
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Staff, new { @id = "staffHidden" })
</div>
```

When the data finally gets to the controller, the Staff property has the correct length, but all the values are set to 0 and the ModelState.IsValid condition fails. I know there is some step I am missing, probably in the editor. Thank you so much for any help.

Comment: can you post your controller?

Comment: figured out the problem - the "property" I was passing as Staff was actually a Staff object, not an int representing its ID. Solved it inside the serializeArray function on the grid partial.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    function serialize(data) {
        for (var property in data) {
            if ($.isArray(data[property])) {
                serializeArray(property, data[property], data);
            }
        }
    }
    function serializeArray(prefix, array, result) {
        if(prefix == "Staff"){
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                result[prefix + "[" + i + "]"] = array[i]["ID"];
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Might be a bit of a hacky solution, but it works and I'm frustrated enough to take it.

Comment: Turns out I had to scrap the whole thing for a different reason and used a view model to contain an array of the entire object and a separate table to connect ProjectIDs to StaffIDs. I'll remember your solution for the future though, thanks mate.